# How to use if/else in a dictionary with dataframes?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, if-statement

I have a dictionary of 1000 dataframes, but to simplify this lets assume now 3 dataframes.

```
d = {'key1': DataFrame, 'key2': DataFrame, 'key3': DataFrame}
```

All dataframes have the same variables: Distance,Country, Price. I want to identify which key contains a dataframe where the Distance Variable is a string. Perhaps by creating a new dictionary whose keys indicate whether the variable distance is string or not.

I tried using the following code but is not working.

```
comprobar = {"str_in_values_of_{}".format(k) if v[v.dtypes['Hour']==np.str] in v else ".".format(k): v for k, v in d.items()}
```

Can someone tell me why is not working?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is

> to identify which key contains a dataframe where the Distance Variable
>   is a string

And assuming `'Distance'` is the column name for your dataframe, then how about:

`[k for k, v in d.items() if any(type(e)==str for e in v['Distance'])]`

This has the added benefit of checking every single entry of the 'Distance' column to see if it's a string; as opposed to checking against `v.dtypes`, which could be heterogeneous in its composition, thereby just giving you a `object` type.

Comment: Yes thats what I want but your code is not working for me, it gives me just a list of one number :(

Comment: @AntoineFa it should give you a list of keys which have string entries in the distance column. It seemed to have worked for me when I used some mock dataframes with data mimicking to yours.

Comment: @AntoineFa is that 1 number a key in your dict of dataframes?